# Why is there no element of $N/K$ has order a power of $p$ (except trivially the identity element)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

This is a question from Chapter 16, A Book of Abstract Algebra by Charles Pinter.

Here are the details from the first two parts of the question (with my own solution) that basically lead to the main problem in the title:

Let $K$ be a p-Sylow subgroup of $G$, and $N=N(K)$ be the normalizer of $K$. Let $a \in N$, and suppose the order of $Ka$ in $N/K$ is a power of $p$. Let $S=<Ka>$ be the cyclic subgroup of $N/K$ generated by $Ka$. Then by the Correspondence Theorem, $S \cong S^{*}/K$ where $S^{*} = \{x \in N:f(x) \in S\}$ and $f$ is a homomorphism from $N$ onto $N/K$. Because $S$ is a p-group, hence $S^{*}/K$ is also a p-group. As $S^{*}$ is a p-subgroup of $G$ (because $K$ and $S^{*}/K$ are p-groups), and by definition $K \subseteq S^{*}$ , hence $K=S^{*}$ and it follows that $Ka=K$ (i.e. every element in the kernel of $N$ gets mapped to the identity element $K$ in $N/K$).

Thus by contradiction, there is no element of $N/K$ that has order a power of $p$ because the order of $K$ in $N/K$ should be 1.

At least that is what I think, however the statement in brackets confused me. I thought even the identity element should not have order a power of $p$. Would anyone please explain why? Also, as a self learner in abstract algebra, I would really appreciate helpful comments on the sketch of proof above. Thanks!

Comment: The identity element is of order $p^0$. There are two sets of brackets in your question you should clarify which confuses you.

Comment: Hi Yanko, thanks I think this is exactly what I'm missing. Perhaps the author is being a little too detailed and I didn't think it'll be that simple. But anyway, do you think the proof is sound?

Comment: It looks find to me.

Comment: Thanks again Yanko!

Comment: This proof seems to be a crazy detour: if $K$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, then it certainly is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of its normalizer $N_G(K)$. Hence $|N_G(K):K|$, which divides $|G:K|$, is never divisible by $p$.

Comment: Hi Dr. Hekster, thanks a lot for the comment! While it's obvious that $K$ is also a Sylow $p-$subgroup of its normalizer $N_G (K)$, I'm not sure why this implies that $|N_G (K) : K|$ is not divisible by $p$. This is quite apparent if we have assumed the Sylow's theorem, but this is one of the steps that the author uses to prove the Sylow theorem.